# Скопировать текст во всплывающий модуль JS

Tags: javascript, dom

По двойному клику на слово в тексте оно копируется в соседний блок в виде элемента списка. Под блоком со списком есть кнопка "Cохранить". По клику на кнопку на середину всплывает модуль без наполнения, просто прямоугольник.

Задача: перенести скопированные из текста слова, которые сформировали список, во всплывающий модуль.

Вот код для кнопки "Сохранить", но он не работает:

function modalList(){
       document.getElementById('paste').value = document.getElementById('copy').innerHTML;
    }

Comment: На codepen  выложите свои наработки так наглядней будет

Comment: Код  можно увидеть по ссылке https://codepen.io/PeterShwed/pen/eQJaxw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправь функцию

```
function myFunction() {
    var wordItem = window.getSelection(); ;
    var copy = document.getElementById("copy");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML= wordItem;
    copy.appendChild(li);
}
```

Исправь

```
<div class="modal-body" >
     <div class="PASTE" id="paste">
        <ul id="paste-list">              
        </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Исправь функцию

```
function modalList(){
   document.getElementById('paste-list').innerHTML = 
 document.getElementById('copy').innerHTML;
 }
```

если помог прими ответ как правильный

Comment: Огромное спасибо!